# How to use unittest's self.assertRaises with exceptions in a generator object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, generator

I got a generator object that I want to unittest. It goes through a loop and, when at the end of the loop a certain variable is still 0 I raise an exception. I want to unittest this, but I don't know how. 
Take this example generator:

```
class Example():
    def generatorExample(self):
        count = 0
        for int in range(1,100):
            count += 1
            yield count   
        if count > 0:
             raise RuntimeError, 'an example error that will always happen'
```

What I would like to do is

```
class testExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_generatorExample(self):
        self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, Example.generatorExample)
```

However, a generator object isn't calable and this gives

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

So how do you test if an exception is raised in a generator function?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`assertRaises`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) is a context manager since Python 2.7, so you can do it like this:

```
class testExample(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_generatorExample(self):
        with self.assertRaises(RuntimeError):
            list(Example().generatorExample())
```

If you have Python < 2.7 then you can use a `lambda` to exhaust the generator:

```
self.assertRaises(RuntimeError, lambda: list(Example().generatorExample()))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to do it in 2.6, if that is possible.

Comment: I've update my answer a moment ago with an example of how to do it in Python < 2.7.

Comment: Is it possible, in 2.6, to extract the exception message?

Comment: @DanielMagnusson you can just do it manually, something like: `try: call(); except MyExcType as e: self.assertEqual(e.message, "my msg"); except Exception as ee: self.fail('Unexpected exception type'); else: self.fail('should have thrown an exc');`

Comment: On another note, can I check like this: `self.assertRaises(SomeException, SomeotherException, callable, *args, *kwargs)`? Basically check for more than one exception, in a call.

Comment: @ApurvaKunkulol I'd assume you can pass multiple exception classes in a tuple like you do with `except (SomeException, SomeOtherException):`.